# Program stops working when leaving out a reference to variable in scanf(). Why is this?

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

Why does this program stop working if I leave out the reference to userNumber in the scanf function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int userNumber;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &userNumber);

    while (userNumber != 10)
    {
        printf("\nWrong number. Try again\n");
        printf("\nEnter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &userNumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *where* do you leave *what* out?

Comment: If you mean you just write `scanf("%d");` -- this is **undefined behavior**. The language requires a parameter to receive the result for each conversion specifier.

Comment: Sidenote: C does not support references. You pass pointers to `scanf`.

Comment: So you ask why your program behaves undefined when you invoke undefined behaviour? I don't see a problem, apparently your code does the expected. What about the documentation is not clear?

Comment: Trying to make some sense of this question: Please tell us what you want to **achieve** by leaving out `&userNumber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scanf("%d")](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) requires to pass a pointer as its second argument, thus you really need to write:

```
int userNumber;
scanf("%d", &userNumber);
```

If you take out the reference, then input is not read correctly, and `userNumber` is actually left **uninitialized**, which causes *Undefined Behavior*, which probably explains the behavior you witness.

You should have seen a warning, if you had removed the reference from the first scanf:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc main.c 
main.c:8:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
      'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d", userNumber);
           ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: uhm. Not the *prototype*. The prototype doesn't tell you anything in case of `scanf()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen yeah you are right, updated, do you like it now?

Comment: Not my downvote, as it's good enogh for such a strange question ... but to be precise, there's no *second argument* required at all. The requirement is that you have to pass a pointer for each conversion in the format string that isn't suppressed with `*`. (so, with `%d` as the format string, the second argument *is* required)

Comment: @FelixPalmen right, edited again, thanks for helping improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Am following a tutorial to learn c and decided to extend on it a bit by adding a loop. I haven't really covered pointers yet, so don't quite understand what is going on here?

Comment: Well, you should study more then and read that chapter, because now it's too broad to explain @Njgardner90. BTW do not forget to *accept* an answer!

Comment: My apologies. I'm new to the whole setup here. Thanks again